# Plugin works for default post types, but not for custom

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I've coded a plugin that adds a meta box to the post page. When the post is published, the plugin will generate a random ID for the post, and insert the random ID and the post guid to a custom table in the database. After publishing, or upon editing, the plugin queries the custom table to retrieve the random ID for the post based on the post guid, and prints out the random ID in the meta box.

Everything works great until I change the post type in the add_meta_box function from 'post' to 'quilt'. The plugin will generate the random ID and save it and the post guid to the table, but presents this error in the meta box:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/qultshow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/randomID/randomID.php on line 126

instead of the random ID. If I use

```
var_dump( $query );
$wpdb->print_error();
```

to try to debug, I see:

> NULL
>
> WordPress database error: [] SELECT * FROM wp_customtable WHERE qrci_guid = "http://testsite.com/?post_type=quilt&p=213"

If I copy the query from the Wordpress database error directly and run it in phpmyadmin, a row is returned as expected. So, the query is coded correctly, and the plugin works on the default post type of "post" but not on the custom post type of "quilt". The only change in the plugin is in this code:

`add_meta_box( 'randomid_sectionid', 'Random ID', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'quilt', 'normal', 'high' );`

where 'post' was changed to 'quilt'.

Is there something odd or different about querying the database from a custom post type that I need to know about to make this work?

Notes: This plugin is not for usage by anyone but me on one website where I need this weird functionality. Also, this is a multi-site installation of wordpress if that makes any difference. I can't use post metadata for this since I need to be able to query this data without querying every postmeta table on the network, so it has to be a custom table in the database.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. Yes, I posted code related to this issue in another question, but I'm hoping that being a bit more clear about what the objective is and how it's working with the default post type but not working with custom post types will find someone who might have the answer to why this isn't working, where posting the code did not.

Comment: But, is this a different Question or not? If it's the same issue, you should work on the previous Q (based on Answers and Comments feedback) and not do a self-duplicate.

Comment: Please do not just ask the same question twice. Edit the original until answers are possible.

Comment: I posted the question here in a more broad, conceptual sense, simply because all of the discussion on the other post is wrapped up in the code, and there's nothing wrong with the code if it works for default post types, and it does. It may not be the best written code, but it does work on a default post type.